# SPQuery - Which fields (ViewFields) are required to Update the list item?

Tags: event-receivers, spquery

In an SPQuery, which fields are required to update a list item?

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = @"
    <OrderBy>
        <FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='true' />
    </OrderBy>";
query.ViewFields = string.Concat(
    "<FieldRef Name='ID' />",
    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />");
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
query.RowLimit = 2000; // Effective batch size.
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

If I run `listItem.Update()` without changing any fields, the update fails with the error `'value does not fall within the expected range'`.  But if I change `ViewFieldsOnly` to false, the update succeeds.  My question is which fields are required to update a list item successfully (excluding any fields that may have been changed)?

Comment: How are you getting the specific list item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it's not documented anywhere which fields should be included to be able to do an Update after querying with ViewFieldOnly set to true, but according to [SPQuery.ViewFieldsOnly and Updating an SPListItem](http://blog.mannsoftware.com/?p=25) it's amongst other ID, UniqueID, object type, ...

**BUT** my recommendation is definitely don't even try, just set ViewFieldsOnly to false, then you're sure you get what's needed even in future versions of SharePoint.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this issue, and have managed to get round it.  I included the ListItem ID in the ViewFields then have created a new SPListItem variable using List.GetItemByID.  You can then do a normal List Item update using this new variable.

```
        SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
        q.Query = "Query here";
        q.ViewFields = "...Fields Here...<FieldRef Name='ID' />";
        q.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

        foreach (SPListItem item in list.GetItems(q))
        {
            SPListItem i = list.GetItemById(int.Parse(item["ID"].ToString()));
            //code to update item here
            i.Update();
        }
```

It may not be the best solution ever but it got me up and running.

Comment: Sorry, but this makes me facepalm. SPList.GetItemById() creates an SPQuery object with all viewfields and rowlimit 1 and queries a list.